# Install specific version of PyTorch to conda environment

Tags: virtualenv, pytorch, conda

Using `Anaconda Navigator` I created a new environment for running someone's `VAE` code off `GitHub` that uses Python 3.6 and PyTorch 0.4.0. Unfortunately, `Anaconda Navigator` doesn't give me the option to install an older version of `PyTorch` on this environment, just the `PyTorch` version I have currently installed. How do I install `PyTorch 0.4.0` only to this new `Conda environment` I created? If it's possible via `Anaconda Navigator`, great! But I assume it's going to be done via a `Conda command`. I definitely don't want to mess up my other environments.

Thanks!

Comment: Check https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#commands-for-versions--100-1

Comment: Thanks! How do I choose which Conda env to install it to though?

Comment: Activate the conda environment you want to install to and then install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just navigate to the conda environment you want to install it, then use

> conda install pytorch=0.4.1 -c pytorch

More details here on how you can install previous PyTorch versions: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

According to this blog, conda navigator does not work, but you can follow it to install pytorch in a conda environment:
https://medium.com/@bryant.kou/how-to-install-pytorch-on-windows-step-by-step-cc4d004adb2a

Answer (score 2):

if you also want to specify the cuda version do this:

```
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```